# How to return struct from class where it is defined?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to return a copy of struct from public class function, and i define this struct inside this class as a private member.

Is it possible to return this structure of any other type of custom data?

Consider this simple example:

```
class Test {
private:
    struct sTest {
        int i = 1;
    }_sTest;
public:
    sTest GetStruct() {
        return _sTest;
    }
};
```

then after i create object of this class:

```
Test cTest;
```

how can i call

```
 cTest.GetStruct()
```

to get

```
 _sTest
```

?

Comment: The problem is that the user who calls GetStruct() doesn't have access to private members and he/she doesn't know the implementation of a structure.

Comment: How do you expect calling code to k now what to do with the `sTest` returned by `GetStruct` if the name `sTest` is private? Technically you could do something like `auto something = sTest.GetStruct();` because only the _name_ `sTest` is private ([demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/6K9jxEs33)), but... why would you want to do that? If an `sTest` is supposed to be meaningful to calling code, make it part of the class's public interface.

Comment: if i will make **sTest** public, then it will not be encapsulated. All i want to do is to read data which is stored in private structure inside class. Are there better ways?

Comment: also i have child classes derived from **cTest**  that overload **GetStruct()** and have their own implementations of **sTest** structure, so i need to make **sTest** unique for every child class

Comment: If you're returning an `sTest` in a public function and you expect calling code to be able to operate directly on an `sTest`, you already aren't "encapsulating" anything because those implementation details need to be known. Perhaps figure out what specific data stored in an `sTest` needs to be exposed to users of the class and write functions that return that?

Comment: For instance, it's conceivable that you'd want to write `int get_i() { return _sTest.i; }`, which allows calling code to access the value of `i` without needing to know that, internally in `Test`, that value happens to be stored inside an implementation struct.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `auto` to store the object.

Following is sample code. [See it here in action](https://ideone.com/PmPf55):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
private:
    struct sTest {
        int i = 1;
    }_sTest;
public:
    sTest GetStruct() {
        return _sTest;
    }
};



int main()
{
    Test a;
    auto obj = a.GetStruct();
    
    cout<< obj.i <<"\nDone!!!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

***Output:***

```
1
Done!!!
```

**Note:** It is fine on other compilers also. Check [here on other compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/a69nM9f69) also.

Comment: thanks, yes, i already figured out this workaround, but i had doubt if this is safe.

Comment: @hgrev I checked on the compilers available on https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ and it seems fine. Non of the compilers complained.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you don't want to declare your struct within your class:

```
// not necessarily a member function
auto GetStruct()
{
  struct sTest {
        int i = 1;
    };
  return sTest();
}

using test_t = decltype(GetStruct()); // you can make an alias for an anonymous struct.
auto test = GetStruct();
```

Comment: thanks, interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Since the private class is not accessible from the class Test outside, use the keyword `auto`.

```
auto test = cTest.GetStruct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly safe. It is like any other type of data. With auto you are just telling the compiler to guess which kind of variable would be.